# Creating indexes based on specific SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-indexes

I have these two tables:

```
orders 
    order_id, customer_id, order_date, product_id, order_quantity

products 
    product_id, ProductName, SupplierID, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock
```

`order_id` and `product_id` are the primary keys.

I want to create indexes based on these queries which are executed regularly

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE product_id = @id

SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE customer_id = @id AND order_date > @date

SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_date > @date1 AND order_date < @date2

SELECT product_id, ProductName, UnitsInstock
FROM products
WHERE UnitsInstock < @units

SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE ProductName = @name AND SupplierID = @Id
```

I am confused on how to create these indexes since I don't know exactly how the '@' symbol works in SQL and how to implement it in a index with where clause statement. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `mysql` and `sql server` are different products; which do you mean?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: The `@` defines a parameter; are the statements above part of a store procedure? You can define indexes on the fields that you are searching which are not primary keys which will have their own indexes- `supplier_id` for example

Comment: like this `CREATE INDEX orders_idx ON orders (product_id)`  or do i need to add the where clause statement somewhere aswell?

Comment: This is an assignment and we are called to suggest indexes that would make the execution of this queries faster but they have gave us little to no information on how to use them and after hours of searching i am kinda confused and frustrated

Comment: It's a one-off run on the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters got nothing to do with the indexes.
The indexes are based on the columns that you use more in the WHERE clause.
In the first table you use more:
product_id
customer_id
order_date
In the second table you use more:
UnitsInstock
ProductName
SupplierID

you can add an index on this columns but just remember that an index is good for querying the table but are bad for inserting and updating in the table (the insert/update is slower).

On other hand the @field are just parameters (you can think of it as variables)
In some other part of the script this parameters are getting the value.

Comment: I think that i understood now. Thanks a lot for your answer!